# Cannot read property substring of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have my below code which is giving error as:

```
Cannot read property substring of undefined (Uncaught type error)
```

Below is my code and I am not able to figure out what's wrong here?

```
function cmt_btnsave(img) {
    $img = $(img);
    $this = $($img.prop('id').replace('img', 'txt'));  //get textarea
    saveComments($this, true);
}

function saveComments($this, isFinal) {
    var controllerFuncParams = new Object();
    controllerFuncParams.sat = "@asi.sat";
    controllerFuncParams.s = "@asi.s";
    controllerFuncParams.sor = "@asi.sor";

    // this line is throwing exception
    controllerFuncParams.c = $this.val().substring(0, "@charmax_eleComment");
    ......
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong here? Any thoughts what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you didn't check if **`$this.val()`** is null.

```
if($this.val()){
 controllerFuncParams.c = $this.val().substring(0, "@charmax_eleComment");
}
```